# filtering entries of HashMap and iterate over values

Tags: java, graph, iterator, hashmap

I have useed a HashMap to implement a graph

```
HashMap<E,Node<E>> graph=new HashMap<E,Node<E>>()
```

now I want to filter the head nodes out of it *(Node class has a method that shows if this node is head or tail)*

```
public Iterator<Node<E>> heads() {
    HashMap<E, Node<E>> heads=new HashMap<E, Node<E>>();
    for(Entry<E, Node<E>> e:graph.entrySet()){
        if(e.getValue().isHead())
            heads.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    return heads.values().iterator();
}
```

I wanted to know if it is a good way of implementation or is there a better proper way ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know in what aspect of "Better" you are looking for.  Your way works anyway.

There is another way I prefer, by using Guava's `Iterables`.

it looks something like:

```
Iterable<Node<E>> heads 
     = Iterables.filter(graph.values(), 
                        new Predicate<Node<E>> {
                            @Override
                            public boolean apply(Node<E> node) {
                                return node.isHead();
                            }
                       );
```

---

Edit: If you are using Java 8, you will already find similar feature without 3rd party lib.  Thanks to Lambda, the syntax is even easier.  Anyway, the idea is the same.

Comment: `Iterables.filter(graph.values(), Node::isHead())` using Java 8 features.

Comment: I should mention Java 8 :) Lemme add a note in my answer

Comment: aha I was seeing "Predicate" in some posts , so it is for Java8.
I am using 7

Comment: no no... the solution I wrote using Predicate is using Guava, which is for JDK5+.  Using Java8 is going to give you even simpler code, as quoted by the first comment.  That means, you can safely take my answer if you are using Java7.

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward improvement over the algorithm you have posted would be to collect the head elements of the map into a list, rather than reconstructing a `HashMap` with just the head elements in it:

```
public Iterator<Node<E>> heads() {
    List<Node<E>> heads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Node<E> e : graph.values()) {
        if (e.isHead())
            heads.add(e);
    }
    return heads.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 version:

```
Iterator<Node> s = graph.values().stream().filter(n -> n.isHead()).iterator();
```